# Adding an external js library to gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to add the UIKit.js and css files to a gatsby project. I'd rather not use the Helmet for this especially with the JS file from UIKit. So I am adding this to the Layout wrapper component

```
componentDidMount() {
   const script = document.createElement("script")
   script.src = withPrefix("/assets/uikit.min.js")
   script.async = true // probably would have to remove this to prevent issues
   document.body.appendChild(script)
}
```

Problem is, it's adding it again and again on every page I navigate to. That's not good. How can I check for it to load once. Or is there a better or more efficient way of doing this

EDIT "npm uikit" is not well-maintained in my experience. And gatsby doesn't have a plugin for it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `browser-gatsby.js` file in root of the project to add global css or other files like this.

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/global-css/#adding-global-styles-without-a-layout-component